# Liquid Markup Multiple Conditions in IF statement

Tags: java, html, liquid

I currently have the code below, but I need to add one more condition to it.  For my second line, I want to add "  or if {{app.recommended}} = 'Yes' and {{app.award_type}} == '' "
But If I add these to the beginning of my if statement or the end, the code does not work properly.  I have even tried using a nested If Statement, but it still does not work.

Basically - If Ranking is blank, or recommend is blank, or (recommend = yes and award_type is blank) than assign a zero.
But Parenthesis do not work in Liquid.  Can someone please help me write this statement?

```
{% for app in myapps %}
{% if {{app.ranking}}  == '' or  {{app.recommended}}  == '' %}
{% assign eligible = '0' %}
{% else %}
{% assign eligible = '1' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add curly braces in to the if condition. Try this code.

```
{% for app in myapps %}
{% if app.ranking  == '' or  app.recommended  == '' %}
{% assign eligible = '0' %}
{% else %}
{% assign eligible = '1' %}
{% endif %}
```